# I have a ticket admin page which I want the view to be seperated for each group

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site

I am trying  to show/display ticket information which should be constrained by Group: "A" can only see tickets opened by "A" and "C", then "B" can only see "B" and "C". Lastly, "C" can see all tickets

I am using SharePoint Online by teamwork. How can I constraint it?

Any help will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ticket information is stored in a SharePoint custom list.

On the admin page, add that list as a webpart and set the Target Audience "A". "A" being a SharePoint group.

[image]

Modify the view to display only those tickets created by "A" or "C".

Add same list again on the admin page and repeat the steps for B and finally for C.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set List Item Level Permission based on the column value programmatically.

Check the articles [Event Receiver to Set Item Level Permissions based on List Column Value](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/09/event-receiver-to-set-item-level-permissions.html)

[Set List Item Level Permission using CSOM](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2016/04/set-list-item-level-permission-using-csom-c-sharp.html)